# Screen Alerts - Android 4.4

Tags: applications, samsung

screen alerts - when, for example, I get some new Whatsup. I do not want to see any new messages are lined up, but I want it to be like it was in the previous version, it says to me, "received 3 new messages" Then I came in INTO the application and read them.

Thanks!!